# algebraic data type for tree

Tags: haskell, tree, algebraic-data-types

I'm trying to build a tree where its children are represented in a list. Each of the children may themselves be subtrees etc. So I go this way --

```
data Children a = NoChildren | Cons a (Children a) deriving (Show, Read, Ord, Eq)
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Children a) deriving (Show, Read, Ord, Eq)
```

now i try to create a tree like this

```
let subtree1 = Node 67 NoChildren
let subtree2 = Node 86 NoChildren
let tree1 = Node 83 (subtree1 `Cons` (subtree2 `Cons` NoChildren))
```

it works fine till subtree2. tree1 is not created. The error thrown is this -

```
<interactive>:96:15:
    No instance for (Num (Tree Integer))
      arising from the literal `83'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (Tree Integer))
    In the first argument of `Node', namely `83'
    In the expression: Node 81 (subtree1 `Cons` (subtree2 `Cons` NoChildren))
    In an equation for `tree1':
      tree1 = Node 81 (subtree1 `Cons` (subtree2 `Cons` NoChildren))
```

I don't understand this error error at all. Why is it complaining that 83 is a literal. subtree1 and subtree2 had literals too and they were fine...

**I solved the problem by doing the following**

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a [Tree a] deriving (Show, Read, Ord, Eq)

flatten [] = []
flatten x:xs = x ++ flatten xs

preorder EmptyTree = []
preorder (Node a []) = [a]
preorder (Node a children) = [a] ++ flatten (map preorder children)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data Children a = NoChildren | Cons a (Children a)
```

means your `Children a` is isomorphic to `[a]`, and hence your

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Children a)
```

is isomorphic to

```
data List a = Empty | Nonempty a [a]
```

which is again isomorphic to `[a]`.

What you want is that the children themselves are `Tree`s, so you should use

```
data Children a = NoChildren | Cons (Tree a) (Children a)
```

or plain

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a [Tree a]
```

The error is because `subtree1` has type `Tree a` for some `a` belonging to `Num` (ditto for `subtree2`). Then when you write

```
tree1 = Node 83 (subtree1 `Cons` (subtree2 `Cons` NoChildren))
```

the inferred type of `tree1` is `Tree (Tree a)` (for some `a` belonging to `Num`), and hence

```
83 :: Tree a
```

But there's no `Num` instance for `Tree`s.

Comment: thanks for the answer and explanation. I had used [Tree a] but it was giving the dreaded "cannot construct the infinite type" error. I resolved that as well.